# Can't handle a button setOnAction event in the Controller

Tags: java, javafx

I'm having problems to handle mouse events. I can't make the button work, me method works but the event handle not.

What i'm doing wrong?

The method where i "initialize" the controller events:

```
public boolean loadScreen(String name, String resource) {
    try {
        FXMLLoader myLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource(resource));
        Parent loadScreen = myLoader.load();
        ControlledScreen myScreenController = myLoader.getController();
        myScreenController.setScreenParent(this);
        myScreenController.initialize(); //here i initialize the event
        groups.put(name,myScreenController.getGroupRoot());
        addScreen(name,loadScreen);
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        return false;
    }
}
```

This is the method in the controller class:

```
public void initialize(){
    dayParting.setOnAction(event->{
        myController.setScreen(Main.DayPartingScreen);
    });
}
```

Comment: Post you full controller code, because I guess there are huge problems regarding. The initialize() method shall be called by the FXMLLoader on the controller instance what it creates when loading the FXML file.

Comment: I fixed it, i was an instance problem as you said. Thanks @DVarga